# Magento admin user created automatically?

Tags: magento-1.9

Magento admin user created automatically. I checked the entire code i couldn't found any script which is creating the admin user pragmatically. 
Is there any MySQL script to generate the admin user ? If yes, Please tell me how o keep securely.

Please help me to fix this.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

I have also seen in many magento sites, admin users are automatically created in admin. But did not able to find it how.

But there is solution to secure your magento access. 
Please use the below steps for security point of view

1. Delete default administrator role
2. update administrator role with no permission access
3. then create a new role with admin access
4. Update all users with new administrator role